# Floating Point Stability

Tags: floating-point

Say I have two rational fractions a/b and c/d that are equal. a, b, c, and d can all be represented as 32 bit signed integers. if i do division with 64 bit floating point numbers will a/b == c/d always?

Comment: If you're testing for equality, you could just use 64-bit *integers* and compare (a*d) with (b*c), and avoid the whole floating point rounding issue altogether.

Comment: 1/2 and 3/6 for example is going to differ for sure.

Comment: 1/2 and 3/6 are not going to differ, why would they? They will be both exactly (1/2) whatever precision used (float double extended...). double(1)/double(3) and double(5)/double(15) would also lead to the same result as long as num.and den. are converted exactly, IEEE / is such that result is exact fraction rounded according to rounding rules (and mode). If intermediate extended precision is used, then a 2nd rounding is performed to double... double(1/extended(3)) might differ from 1/double(3)... If both fractions pass through the same rounding stages though, result should be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are cases where compiler optimizations will prevent the equality from being true even if the results are guaranteed identical. The original x86 floating point operations are performed on 80-bit registers; if you compare one of those to a stored 64-bit value it will probably compare unequal.

Comment: it would be nice to be able to see some code that would show this problem. i've tried doing this in java and can't seem to force a 64 bit comparison with an 80 bit value.

Comment: There are multiple compilers for Intel targets, and they do not all implement floating-point operations with 80-bit values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you're right - modern compilers may implement floating point with SSE and avoid the 80-bit registers altogether. Since the question asked about "always" I felt a single counter-example was enough.

Comment: @benmmurphy, it's possible that Java doesn't suffer from this problem, either because it doesn't use the older 80-bit floating point instructions or because it always stores the result before comparing it.

Comment: Java does not give the implementation latitude to use extra precision the way C does. It is not required to “store” the result before comparing; it is simply required to calculate with double precision (given double-precision operands), period.